# RelationClasses versus CRelationClasses

Tags: coq

The Coq standard library has two subsets of classes modules, one anchored in `Coq.Classes.RelationClasses` and the other in `Coq.Classes.CRelationClasses`. The latter seems to have been added more recently (2012).

I must be missing something obvious as they both look very similar to me.

What is the reason they exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference is in the type of relations they support:

```
(* RelationClasses, actually defined in Relation_Definitions *)
Definition relation (A : Type) := A -> A -> Prop.

(* CRelationClasses *)
Definition crelation (A : Type) := A -> A -> Type.
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't stare long enough at the definition of `crelation`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `crelation` producing a `Type` instead of a `Prop`, another key difference is that `crelation` is universe polymorphic, but `relation` is not.

```
Require Import Relation_Definitions.
Require Import Coq.Classes.CRelationClasses.
Set Printing Universes.

Print relation.
(*
relation =
fun A : Type@{Coq.Relations.Relation_Definitions.1} => A -> A -> Prop
     : Type@{Coq.Relations.Relation_Definitions.1} ->
       Type@{max(Set+1,Coq.Relations.Relation_Definitions.1)}
 *)

Print crelation.
(*
crelation@{u u0} =
fun A : Type@{u} => A -> A -> Type@{u0}
     : Type@{u} -> Type@{max(u,u0+1)}
(* u u0 |=  *)
 *)

Check (fun (R: crelation (Type -> Type)) => R crelation).

Fail Check (fun (R: relation (Type -> Type)) => R relation).
(*
The command has indeed failed with message:
In environment
R : relation (Type@{test.7} -> Type@{test.8})
The term "relation" has type
 "Type@{Coq.Relations.Relation_Definitions.1} ->
  Type@{max(Set+1,Coq.Relations.Relation_Definitions.1)}"
while it is expected to have type "Type@{test.7} -> Type@{test.8}"
(universe inconsistency: Cannot enforce Coq.Relations.Relation_Definitions.1
<= test.8 because test.8 < Coq.Relations.Relation_Definitions.1).
 *)
```